Two definitions of an Ehresmann connection
There seem to be two related but distinct definitions for a connection on a principal bundle. I'm trying to understand how they relate.
Definition 1: Let $P \xrightarrow{\pi} M$ be a principal bundle. This produces a map $d\pi:TP\rightarrow TM$. Then, an Ehresmann connection is a choice of horizontal subspace $H\subset TP$ such that $TP=H\oplus V$, where $V=\mathrm{ker}(d\pi)$.
Definition 2: Let $P \xrightarrow{\pi} M$ be a principal bundle. This produces a map $d\pi':TP\rightarrow\pi^*(TM)$, where $\pi^*(TM)$ is the pullback bundle. Then, an Ehresmann connection is a choice of horizontal subspace $H\subset TP$ such that $TP=H\oplus V$, where $V=\mathrm{ker}(d\pi')$.
Is the second version somehow more general?

Ehresmann connection should be a right-invariant horizontal subbundle.

It is the same since $d\pi = \tilde\pi\circ d\pi'$ where $\tilde \pi: \pi^*(TM) \to TM$ is the natural map of the pullback square. $\tilde \pi$ is a linear isomorphism in each fibre and therefore $\ker d\pi = \ker (\tilde \pi\circ d\pi') = \ker d\pi'$.
